# Django keeps redirecting to login page

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I am using Django(1.7) to write an app.
I create a new app named **practice** and each time I click on a link inside this app's url, it redirects to login page with the url like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/practice/practice-topics/

Here are the codes I am trying:

In root urls (I have problem with practice app, other apps are fine):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # accounts
    url(r'^accounts/', include('account.urls')),
    # question
    url(r'^question/', include('question.urls')),
    # assignment
    url(r'^assignment/', include('assignment.urls')),
    # onlinetest
    url(r'^onlinetest/', include('onlinetest.urls')),
    # practice
    url(r'^practice/', include('practice.urls')),
    # global
    url(r'^', include('appglobal.urls')),
    # admin
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)+ static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT) # serve files uploaded by user
```

In practice/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^practice-topics/$', 'practice_topic_list', name='practice-topic-list'),
)
```

In practice/views.py

```
def practice_topic_list(request):
    return render(request,'practice_topic_list.html')
```

And in root setting.py, I already had session in INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # my app modules
    'question',
    'practice',
    'assignment',
    'onlinetest',
    'account',
    'appglobal',
)
```

Comment: you don't happen to use login_required decorator in your view ?

Comment: i do not use login_required before the practice_topic_list above in practice/views.py

Comment: after creating practice app in my project, do i need to do any more configurations in setting.py beside adding 'practice' to INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: no , based on your redirect url i think it happens in the view ... so try changing you view code and see what happens .... i suggest removing parts of code starting with `login_required` and `auth` related codes

Comment: This redirect usually happens when you have a login_required method decorator, can you update question with your settings.py file?

Comment: i dont use login_required anywhere in the views.py
@ max: in fact i tried to keep the views as simple as possible like you say to see how it goes. i just return some dumb html file like above but the problem still remains.
@ rajesh: i can still operate normally with my 'question' part

Comment: @3d510 Have you managed to solve this? I am getting a similar issue...